# Loading .txt Files from assets using rootBundle

Tags: flutter

Dear Stackoverflow community,

my goal is to load a simple text file (.txt) as string using the loadString. rootBundle. unfortunately it does not work and I get the following error:  [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected extension byte (at offset 250).

If I open the same file in an Texteditor and copy it's content to a new text file and use rootBundle to open the new file it works perfectly.

Thank you for any help on this

this is my code

```
import 'fluxData.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';



class FluxBrain {
 

  String data;


  Future<void> getTheData() async {
    data = await rootBundle.loadString('textFiles/textDemo.txt');

}
}
```

Comment: Did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't solve the problem, but I found the sign that caused the trouble. The text files I am trying to read contain Temperatures with  a ° sign. Namely the Unexpected extension byte (at offset 250) causing the error.

Opening the file in android studio or TextEdit the ° appears as an infinity sign (TEMPERATURE (∞C)). and this infinity sign is not readable. I think the problem is that the files were generated by an Microsoft based PDA (portable device).. The same text files generated by an Android device did not cause this problem.